# Make a ScrollView scroll to the bottom when the soft keyboard appears in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

So I am making a texting app just to mess around with the different things in android programming and have yet to run into a problem that I can't find the answer for online. I have tried several different answers from this site and other android programming forums and not one of them has worked every time. There are some examples that work every other time, whereas other examples will work only once. This is the only thing left in the app that I need to figure out for UI functionality.

I have an XML layout file as such:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlActionBar2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlAddContact"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlActionBar2"
        android:background="@drawable/new_message_background"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/text_to"
            android:textColor="#7F7F7F"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtContact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvTo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddContact"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvTo"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:hint="@string/contact_name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddContact"
            android:layout_width="28.5dp"
            android:layout_height="28.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_button"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svMessageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlNewMessage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/rlAddContact"
        android:background="#DBE2ED" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llMessages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#DBE2ED"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="11dp" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlNewMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/messagebar_background"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAttatchment"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtMessageBox"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMessageBox"
            android:layout_width="253dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnAttatchment"
            android:background="@drawable/messagebox_background"
            android:hint="@string/app_name"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:minHeight="26dp"
            android:textSize="17sp" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txtMessageBox"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button"
            android:text="@string/send_button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is getting the ScrollView *svMessageView* to automatically scroll to the bottom every time the soft keyboard comes onto the screen for the user to type. The RelativeLayout *rlNewMessage* moves up when the keyboard appears, and the bottom of *svMessageView* is set to stick to the top of *rlNewMessage* and that works, but I can't get the *svMessageView* to scroll to the bottom by itself.

Images:

After soft keyboard loads (not what I want): https://i.stack.imgur.com/47zD9.jpg

After soft keyboard loads (what I want): https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3IkH.jpg

If more information is needed for you to figure out the problem let me know and I will post it asap.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it, but you may try scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); on EditText touch listener perhaps.

Comment: This wont work due to the animation that opens the keyboard will be too delayed. While you could use a timer for this, its very ill advised due to dropped frames etc

Answer (score -2):

Add this in your `Manifest.xml` for `Activity` and feed me back

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: I can see where my question was confusing about what I want to achieve. Everything behaves normally for the app right now. I just need to figure out the code needed to scroll the scrollview to the bottom (to show the last message) everytime the soft keyboard comes onto the screen. I'm getting screenshots to post as well as that will probably clarify my question.

Comment: @vlllc, have you some workout for your question?? cos I have similar question )